# Code::Blocks и проблемы с автодополнением

Tags: c, ide, codeblocks

Я использую **Code::Blocks** на протяжении длительного времени. Насколько помню, у этой **IDE** всегда были болячки:

- Внезапные падения при изменении размеров элементов интерфейса;
- Повисшие процессы отладки;
- Багающиеся настройки компиляции;
- Автоподстановка не того, что выбрано;
- Через раз работающий дизассемблер.

Это все можно было терпеть...

Но в какой-то момент я заметил, что больше не могу перейти к месту определения/объявления того или иного идентификатора. Не важно, что это, - макрос, функция или структура.

Не могу посмотреть даже такие элементарные определения, как **printf()**, **WM_DESTROY**, **CHAR**.

Думал, что *само пройдет*, но не прошло...

Я пробовал переустанавливать **Code::Blocks**. Менял компиляторы, полагая, что парсер давится кривыми заголовками. Обновлял операционную систему. Экспериментировал с настройками автодополнения и парсинга.

Проблему решить не удалось...

1) С чем эта проблема может быть связана?

2) Каковы варианты ее решения?

3) Если починить **Code::Blocks** нельзя, то какую **IDE** вы могли бы мне порекомендовать? Я разрабатываю для **Windows** и в основном использую компиляторы **MinGW**, пишу исключительно на **C**. Менять **IDE** не хочется, потому очень к ней привык, но терпеть такое больше не могу.

Мне в принципе от **IDE** многого не надо.

Я пробовал **Qt Creator**, но он слишком избыточный, к тому же из коробки с ним идут какие-то глупые проблемы, вроде багов с кодировками вывода компилятора.

**CodeLite** не подошел потому, что пару раз упал при настройках путей к компилятору.

**NetBeans** оказался слишком тяжелым и медленным.

Comment: Посмотрите на pellecC http://www.smorgasbordet.com/pellesc/ - там правда в комплекте есть свой компилятор, но может его как раз с головой и хватит. Очень интересный и приятный.

Comment: Под Windows удобно пользоваться Visual Studio. К ней якобы можно прикрутить другие компиляторы. Или еще проще - отлаживать на родном микрософтовском компиляторе, а релиз делать на MinGW (если это так принципиально).

Comment: @KoVadim, Pellec C не годится. В нем нет навигации по определениям символов, скудная подсветка, неясные сообщения об ошибках, неясная совместимость с открытыми библиотеками.

Comment: @pepsicoca1, студия самая удобная, это бесспорно, но прикрутка к ней стороннего компилятора - тот еще квест.

Comment: [тот еще квест.] Я тоже ниасилил прикрутить к студии сторонний компилятор. Поэтому делал так - отлаживался в студии, а релиз делал на нужном компиляторе в батнике из командной строки. Причем нужный компилятор был не под х86 платформу. Очень удобно, кстати.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Откройте настройки: `Settings - Compiler - Global compiler settings`;
- выберите свой компилятор из списка;
- на вкладке `Search directories` добавьте полный путь к паке Include используемого вами компилятора;
- сохраните настройки и перезапустите CodeBlocks.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Я думал, что пути поиска необходимы только для того, чтобы объяснить компилятору, где искать используемые ресурсы. Получается, эти пути используются еще и парсером? Где можно найти документацию по этим моментам? Я до сих пор не совсем понимаю, чем, например, отличается **Linker settings->Link libraries** от **Search directories->Linker**

Comment: @МаксимГлухманюк Где об этом написано не знаю, мне оно как-то и так понятно. По поводу опций линкера: первая опция - это то, что передаётся с ключом `-l` (`--library`), вторая - с ключом `-L` (`--library-path`). https://linux.die.net/man/1/ld

Comment: я не очень хорошо понимаю, чем первое отличается от второго.

Comment: @МаксимГлухманюк Первое - имя библиотеки, второе - где её искать на диске (если она вдруг лежит не в дефолтной папке).